# Salesforce object field not getting created after pushing item via DEF

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and DEF 2.1.0 and trying to create a new value in the field in Salesforce object from Sitecore Item. I've created all accessor set and value mapping sets and configured pipelines to do this operation. I failed in doing so, giving error in logs like this:

> ManagedPoolThread #2 07:28:55 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Trying to update
>   salesforce object. (pipeline: Handle Single Row From Sitecore
>   Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Single Salesforce Object Pipeline
>   Step, pipeline step identifier: c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #2 07:28:55 ERROR [Data Exchange] Error duting
>   creating. (object name: ACE_Booking__c) (pipeline: Handle Single Row
>   From Sitecore Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Single Salesforce Object
>   Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier:
>   c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #2 07:28:55 ERROR [Data Exchange] One or more errors
>   occurred. (pipeline: Handle Single Row From Sitecore Pipeline,
>   pipeline step: Submit Single Salesforce Object Pipeline Step, pipeline
>   step identifier: c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #2 07:28:55 ERROR [Data Exchange] START AGGREGATE
>   EXCEPTION (pipeline: Handle Single Row From Sitecore Pipeline,
>   pipeline step: Submit Single Salesforce Object Pipeline Step, pipeline
>   step identifier: c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a, ID: 2, HResult:
>   -2146233088)
>
> ---- Error duting creating. (object name: ACE_Booking__c) (pipeline: Handle Single Row From Sitecore Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Single
>   Salesforce Object Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier:
>   c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a)
>
> Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security
>   settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your
>   profile or permission set. (pipeline: Handle Single Row From Sitecore
>   Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Single Salesforce Object Pipeline
>   Step, pipeline step identifier: c3d7674f-4938-4af5-9742-7fa4d247457a)

I'm creating pipeline steps like this:

[image]

Please guide me how to fix the error.

Comment: The stack trace gives you something to look at: `Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.`

Comment: I'm the administrator of Salesforce account.